# Integration test with fixtures in grails

Tags: mongodb, grails, fixtures, gorm-mongodb

In my Integration test, I have `@Shared` fields that are loaded from fixtures(Fixtures plugin for grails). Those fields are aliases for the fixture beans. Look at the code I have now!

```
@TestFor(OrganizationUserService)
class OrganizationUserServiceSpec extends Specification {

    def fixtureLoader

    @Shared
    def fixture

    @Shared
    def activeOrganizationOne
    @Shared
    def activeChild1

    def setup() {

        fixture = fixtureLoader.load {
            build {
                activeOrganizationOne(Organization) {
                    name = "Active Organization"
                    active = true
                    parent = null
                }

                activeChild1(Organization) {
                    name = "Active Child One"
                    active = true
                    parent = activeOrganizationOne
                }

        }

        activeOrganizationOne = fixture.activeOrganizationOne
        activeChild1 = fixture.activeChild1

    }

    void "deactivateOrganization deactivates an organization and all its children"() {
        given:
            service.organizationService = new OrganizationService()
            service.userService = new UserService()


        when:
            service.deactivateOrganization(activeOrganizationOne)
            //the above method deactivates activeOrganizationOne and activeChild1
            //and activeChild1 will have a disableReason = PARENT_DEACTIVATION
        then:

            !activeOrganizationOne.active

            !activeChild1.active
            DisableReason.PARENT_DEACTIVATION.toString() == activeChild1.disableReason.toString()
    }
}
```

Surprising it is for me that it works. activeChild1 is found by the service method via GORM request. How is it then the `@Shared` object in the test class modified?

To explain more, `deactivateOrganization` gets the childs of the organization using `Organization.findAllByParent(org)`. In which `org` is the parameter passed to `deactivateOrganization`. if `deactivateOrganization` only modifies the objects that are returned from the GORM call, then how does `@shared` fields in the test catch the change? I didn't refresh anything.

I am on Grails 2.3.11 and running with mongoDB.

I am trying to create a standard on how to right Integration tests. So, I want to know the right way to work with fixtures and Integration tests.

Thanks In Advance;